# Java stream returning a Map

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I get the following problem solved using Java Streams?

**Given:-**

```
class Dress {
    private String brandName;
    private String color;

    public String getBrandName() {
        return brandName;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}


List<Dress> dresses = getDresses(); // API call
```

**Required:-**

```
// Number of dresses per color

Map<String, Integer> colorToCountMap;
```

Comment: `Map<String, Integer> colorToCountMap = dresses.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dress::getColor, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)));`

Comment: @shmosel thank you, it works! If you can post it as an answer I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: @ParagKadam You may draft, post, and accept an Answer to your own Question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can live with `Long` instead of `Integer`, you can use [`Collectors.counting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting()) as downstream collector:

```
private record Dress(String brandName, String color) {}
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Long> result = Stream.of(new Dress("One", "Red"), new Dress("Two", "Green"), new Dress("Three", "Red"))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dress::color, Collectors.counting()));
        
    result.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
}
```

If it has to be `Integer`, you can use `Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)` as mentioned in the comments:

```
    Map<String, Integer> result = Stream.of(new Dress("One", "Red"), new Dress("Two", "Green"), new Dress("Three", "Red"))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dress::color, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)));
```

Comment: That return Map<String, Long> map need Map<String, Integer> map

Comment: Added the version with `Integer` as code example.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `Map<String, Integer>` map using following code

```
        Map<String, Integer> colorToCountMap = dresses.stream().
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Dress::getColor, e -> 1, Math::addExact));
```

Comment: Or `Integer::sum`